# in smartpy, local variable param, what's difference?

Tags: smartpy

in smartpy

```
def aa(self) {
    value_in_func = "1234"
    msg = "abc" + value_in_func
    hex_string = msg.encode("utf-8")
    thingToSign = sp.bytes("0x" + hex_string.hex())
}
```

This is working well, But

```
value = "1234"
def aa(self, value)
{
    msg = "abc" + value
    hex_string = msg.encode("utf-8")
    thingToSign = sp.bytes("0x" + hex_string.hex())
}
```

is NOT working.
Error: **call**() missing 1 positional argument: arg

I don't know the difference between the two.

what's difference?

I checked sp.verify(value_in_func == value), this is true.

Comment: You have two different things called value in your second example...

Comment: The consequence is that you’re trying to call encode on a SmartPy expression.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is that you are not passing a parameter to the method:

Your test should contain something like this

```
    c1 = YourContract(...)
    scenario += c1
    scenario += c1.aa("1234")
```

And remove the `value = "1234"`